# Synchronous methods in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I have to write a synchronous function in express js to fetch data from mySQL.

How to get the data for the 'select query' given below

Note:I donot write Asynchronous callback function

Please Advice..

```
  app.get('/get',cors(), function(request,response) {

     var result = connection.query("SELECT id FROM Gantt");
     console.log(result);
    });
```

I tried in the given below

```
app.get('/get',cors(), function(request,response) {
var query1 = connection.query('SELECT id FROM Gantt');
query1.on('result', function(row) {
    console.log(row);
  });
console.log("hi");
});
```

When I run this,
I get 
hi
{id:1}
{id:2}

But I need like this,
{id:1}
{id:2}
hi

please help

Comment: Don't use nodejs if you want synchronous stuff.

Comment: You should use the event style if you dont want to use callback functions. See this: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#streaming-query-rows

Comment: I doubt any db driver allows synchronous connections. There's no such possibility with raw node.js. It might be possible with C extension though. Concluding: you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I really don't see the problem here. Just move the `"hi"` inside the `query1.on()` callback. You don't like it? Too bad - that's just how node.js works. Learn to live with it.